# Divs overlapping and going wrong speed

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a diep.io mini game on codepen, and you can upgrade reload and shoot, however when you shoot more than twice, the bullets go at different speeds and overlap each other.
You can see for yourself here:

https://codepen.io/TheAndersMan/pen/gwKmYy

Here is my HTML:

```
    <div class="wrap">
      <div class="body"></div>
      <div class="barrel"></div>
      <div class="bullets">
      </div>
    </div>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
    .wrap {
      position: absolute;
      top: 30vh;
      left: 40vw;
      display: flex;
    }
    .wrap .body {
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      background: #00b2e1;
      border-radius: 100%;
      border: 6px solid black;
      z-index: 1;
    }
    .wrap .barrel {
      width: 150px;
      height: 125px;
      background: #666;
      margin-top: calc(75px / 2);
      margin-left: -50px;
      z-index: 0;
      border: 6px solid black;
    }
    .wrap .bullets {
      margin-top: calc(75px / 2);
      margin-left: -125px;
      display: flex;
    }
    .wrap .bullets .bullet {
      width: 125px;
      height: 125px;
      border-radius: 100%;
      background: #F14E54;
      border: 6px solid black;
      animation: bulletMove 3s linear 1;
    }

    @keyframes bulletMove {
      0% {
        margin-left: -125px;
      }
      100% {
        margin-left: 60vw;
      }
    }
```

And my JS:

```
    var fireRate = 1,
      fireInterval = null,
      loadNum = 0;

    function fire() {
      console.log("BAM!");
      let bullet = document.createElement("div");
      document.body.appendChild(bullet);
      bullet.classList.add("bullet");
      setTimeout(function() {
        bullet.remove();
      }, 2000)
      document.querySelector(".bullets").appendChild(bullet);
    }

    function startFire() {
      fire();
      fireInterval = setInterval(fire, 1000 / fireRate);
    }

    function stopFire() {
      clearInterval(fireInterval);
    }
```

Sorry, it's a lot, I just want to give you the (almost) full picture, It would probably make more sense if you actually went to the pen and saw it yourself.

So if you can help me fix why the bullets change speeds and overlap that would be great.

Comment: What I think its happening is, that the div creates within "let bullet;" and when you call it again, there is already an instance of it running, so it starts from the current bullet, is not overlapping, its starting at where the first bullet is going at the time, and then it fire the second bullet from the start. You might want to change the way you are creating those div elements and how you are appending those childs?

Comment: @Leo How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Maybe trying to create a different bullet variable each time it fires? I think somewhere around that is your problem, if I were in JQuery for example, I would clone that element for it to be separate from the other .bullet DOM element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[My variant.](https://codepen.io/ouroborus/pen/NRLGJo)

So here's what I think is going on.

You create `div.bullet` and attach it to the `.bullets` container. Then you use `left-margin` to animate them. The thing is, the margin will push the item and all later siblings because it affects inline flow, essentially creating a gap rather than truly moving anything. (`display:flex` makes them essentially inline rather than block-level.)

Imagine you have three elements that are siblings and are set as `display:inline`. Setting `margin-left` on the second one would cause both the second and third one to change position.

In my variant, I switched to absolute positioning and used `left` to position them. This brings them out of the normal flow of the document so that they no longer have an impact on their surrounding elements. (I also changed `z-index` a little.)

I notice it looked like you tried doing this, but it also looks like you didn't put `position:absolute` on the parent and so the positioning was messed up.

Comment: Thanks! That is exactly what I needed.